# How to get passed "could not find server" for a linked server select within an if exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the title gore, I'm working between production and dev environments and do not want to link certain servers in the dev environment.

For any sp with a select from a linked server I could easily put:

```
if exists(select srvname from master.dbo.sysservers where srvname = @server)
begin
select from @server
end
```

But then I have get the error when I try to update the stored procedure:

> Could not find server @server in sys.servers.

Is there an elegant way around this so that I could keep the stored procedures the same for both environments rather than just commenting the selects out in dev?

Comment: `select from @server` whlie `@server` is just server name? Are you sure? Can you provide *more relevant* code you're experiencing problems with?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Well, the error code has an issue with the _server_ not being found in the dev environment. It's really a select from server.DB.dbo.table if that's of any help. Thank you.

Comment: Well, in any case you can wrap your select into dynamic sql - and this will prevent error you're getting on updating procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to setup synonyms for tables that exist in databases that are different between DEV/PROD. Example: in DEV I want to use the table `DatabaseDEV.dbo.UserAccount' and during PROD I want to use the table`DatabasePROD.dbo.UserAccount'.

What I do is setup a SYNONYM like this in DEV:

`CREATE SYNONYM dbo.UserAccount FOR DatabaseDEV.dbo.UserAccount`

And setup a SYNONYM like this in PROD:

`CREATE SYNONYM dbo.UserAccount FOR DatabasePROD.dbo.UserAccount`

Then in my code I reference `SELECT * FROM dbo.UserAccount`. As the SPROC/VIEW is moved from DEV --> PROD it changes from one database to the other. This also works if you have a linked server.